# How to migrate Network Dataset in WGS84 to Web Mercator projection using ArcGIS 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

regards 
I'm using Arcgis 10.1 I need to migrate a Network Dataset developed in WGS84 to Web Mercator projection, I could tell the steps to do this

I want to automate this process in model builder, but I need to know the steps to make the change from WGS84 to Web Mercator projection

could help me please

Answer (score 1):

To change the projection, you'd want to use the Project tool located in the Data Management Tools => Projections and Transformations toolbox.

However, if I'm not mistaken, Web Mercator is already using the WGS84 datum so your geometry is going to look the same.